# How to save backslashes in database via wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress and want to save the pattern ".*www.site.com" in database.

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (1, 'pattern', '.*www\.site\.com')");
```

It saves it without backslashes ".*www.site.com".

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In php you can print backslash as following:
`echo 'abc\xyz'; //use single slash if you are using single quotes(')`
or

```
echo "abc\\xyz"; //Use double slash if you are using double quotes;
```

so for you write query as:
`$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) VALUES (1, 'pattern', '.*www\\.site\\.com')");`